# How to check if channel is open in worker?

Tags: go

Here is what I'm doing: a few workers and queue with job for them.

I have a simple worker:

```
func worker(jobs <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for work := range jobs {
        perform(work)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Start them:

```
    jobs := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for w := 1; w <= parallel; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(jobs, &wg)
    }
```

Also I have a queue, and here goes problem, how to check if there is available worker and write only then?

```
func queue(jobs chan int, stop chan bool) {
    for {
            select {
            case jobs<-?: // How to check what worker is available?
                work := receiveWork()
                jobs <- work
                continue
            case <-stop:
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Start queue:

```
stop := make(chan bool)
go queue(jobs, stop)
```

Note what `receiveWork()` should be called only if there is an available worker.

Comment: What is "available"? Any workers at all? Or at least one worker receiving on jobs?

Comment: See answer for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to use two channels, one for ready and one for the actual work:

```
func worker(ready chan struct{}, work chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for range ready {
        w, ok := <-work
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        perform(w)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func queue(ready chan struct{}, work chan int, stop chan struct{}) {
    defer close(ready)
    defer close(work)
    for {
        select {
        case ready <- struct{}{}:
            work <- receiveWork()
        case <-stop:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Lpo4FogOoeS)

Comment: Bot how to finish faster if there is always worker ready for job? How to stop it?

Comment: Also there is a deadlock possible.

Comment: Stop it by closing the `stop` channel as shown on the playground example.